# Browser: Google Cloud Messaging/node-gcm - data is always null

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-messaging, web-push, node-gcm

Serverside code:

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: "demo",
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    data: {
        test: 'value'
    }
});

var sender = new gcm.Sender(config.gcmKey);

var tokens = [];

... (to add tokens) ... 

sender.send(message, tokens, 3, function (err, res) { ... }
```

Clientside code (in a working serviceworker):

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message', event);
    var title = 'Push message';
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body: 'Test',
            icon: 'img/icon.png',
        }));
});
```

(Everything is copied from readmes, tutorials and demos)

When I send the notification serverside, it displays on my screen as expected and with no errors. However, the `console.log('Push message', event);` outputs the event object with `data: null`. How can I get the `test: 'value'` key-value pair from the server? This is with the latest node-gcm and Chrome 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload for web push notifications doesn't work the same way as it works for Android. It needs to be encrypted and sent in a different way.

You can use the [web-push library](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) for Node.js. It supports GCM for older Chrome versions, Web Push for Firefox and newer Chrome versions.